# \num changes font after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: fonts, formatting, number

There is a certain font I would like to use for a document, and the rendered numbers look like this.

`{1234}`

[image: fotn without \num]

I would like to control the placement of the decimal point too, however, once a number goes through \num,  the font is replaced by LaTex default

`\num[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=3, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]{1234}`

[image: font with \num]

This started happening after the latest update to Ubuntu 22.04. Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks!

Amended: here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{
    Ligatures = TeX,
    Path      = ./Fonts/ }

\IfFileExists{./Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf}{
    \setmainfont[ BoldFont = OpenSans-Bold, ItalicFont = OpenSans-Italic ]{OpenSans-Regular}
    \setsansfont[ BoldFont = OpenSans-Bold, ItalicFont = OpenSans-Italic ]{OpenSans-Regular}
}{}

\begin{document}

{1234}

\addvspace{4ex}

\num[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=3, round-mode=places, round-precision=2]{1234}

\end{document}
```

It has to be compiled with xelatex, and a sub-folde called Fonts whould be present:

```
├── Fonts
│   ├── OpenSans-Bold.ttf
│   ├── OpenSans-Italic.ttf
│   ├── OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf
│   └── OpenSans-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: We will need a Minimal Working Example of your input. Also note that the version of `siunitx`, rather than your OS, is what is important.

Comment: Thanks - not sure how to find the `siunitx` version ...

Comment: When you build the file, a log file is generated (extension `.log`). Search for `siunitx` in the log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change happens as I have revised how `siunitx` deals with detecting sanserif fonts. In particular, in version 3, simply making the  the *text* font 'sanserif-looking' won't affect the output. That happens as the standard settings use math mode, and you'll find that still uses Computer Modern in your demo.

Almost certainly you are expecting text mode fonts, so adding `\sisetup{mode = text}` will work for both the updated system and the older one.

Comment: Yes, this (`\sisetup{mode = text}`)  fixed it, thanks!